# How to attach a debugger to a WebService?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, web-services, remote-debugging

I have 2 projects running on the same machine.(running in Windows XP)

1. Windows Forms Application .Net 2.0 running in VS 2005
2. A webservice(not WCF) running in .Net 4.0 in VS 2010

When I hit F5 in my webserivce runs in debug mode and is setup with IIS(So I guess it copies the new code to the IIS ...This is still on the same machine)

So I can have them both running in debug mode(by press F5). However the windows application calls this webservice up. When it does this I would like it to hit my break points in the ***webservice*** so I can debug.

I am not sure how to do this. I am not sure what I need to attach, Where do I attach it(through VS 2010 or VS 2005).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach the Visual Studio debugger to a process by:

```
Debug > Attach to Process > Attach
```

Where after you select `Attach to Process` you browse the available processes for the one you're looking for. If you service is running in Debug with symbols, that should work. You can then put breaks in your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach to all w3wp.exe processes (IIS app pools). This is done through the "Attach to process..." option in the "Debug" menu.

Comment: ya I don't see that. I see aspnet_wp.exe but it won't let me attach it

Comment: Mark "Show processes from all users" and "Show processes from all sessions". You might need to run Visual Studio with admin rights

Comment: In my case, I had to attach to iisexpress.exe

Answer (score 1):

Open your WebService Project, choose "Debug"-"Attach To Process...". Select w3wp.exe and then click on "Attach"